# How to plot a horizontal line in TradingView at the closing price of the last trading day of the previous year?

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to pine-script and I thought this would be simple, but I'm struggling for a few hours now without much success. I would appreciate help with figuring out how to plot a horizontal line at the closing price of the last trading day. Here is an example of what I was trying to create.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var line    myLine          = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right, color=color.red)
var float   prevYearClose   = na

if year != year[1]
    // Move line
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index-1, close[1])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index  , close[1])
```